# is it possible to make a window_type_dock to show in only 1 workspace on i3 window manager

Tags: linux, archlinux, dock, window-managers, i3

I am struggling to force a dock to show in only 1 workspace and not any other.
Im currently using elkowar's eww widget to make a dashboard.
the problem with it is it kept following me around, overlapping all the other window.

Here is an example, the only way to turn it off is `killall eww`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a `killall eww` you can simply use the toggle flag while opening the dashboard.

Suppose you add a keybinding to open or maybe simply a click event somewhere, you would be running `eww open dashboard`

So instead you can do is set the command to `eww open dashboard --toggle` and you can simply press the same keybinding or click that opens the dashboard.

Another simple solution is to simply add a button to the dashboard that closes it `eww close dashboard`. It might look beautiful to as an addition.

Please let me know if that works for you.